# Using Loop for calculating NDVI in R?

Tags: raster, r, ndvi, loop

I am using MOD09Q1 now and I would like to calculating NDVI whole year data. One year, I have 46 band 1 images and 46 band 2 images.

1. `list.files`

I creating list of band 1 and list of band 2.

```
Band1list  <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "*.b01.tif", all.files = FALSE,
                         full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
                         ignore.case = FALSE)  

Band2list  <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "*.b02.tif", all.files = FALSE,
                         full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
                         ignore.case = FALSE)
```

2. `raster::stack`

Stacking all 46 band 1 (band 2) images to 'StackBand1' ('StackBand2')

```
StackBand1 <- stack(Band1list)

StackBand2 <- stack(Band2list)
```

3. NDVI calculation via `for` loop

I try to stack images of same date (e.g. "2012.01.01.Smb01.tif" and "2012.01.01.Smb02.tif") and calculate NDVI

```
for (i in 1:length(Band1list))
{
  StackBand1[[i]] == i

  StackBand2[[i]] == i 

  Stack <- brick(StackBand1[[i]],StackBand2[[i]])
}
```

In here, I could not execute loop for all 46 images. It can be run all and result is showed for the last couple only.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please format your code for readability using edit > code sample.

Comment: You are overwriting the variable `Stack` in every loop

Comment: In addition to the observation made by @Iris , you aren't really calculating anything in your loop. No NDVI calculations or anything.

Comment: Why not use their ready NDVI or EVI products? http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/dataproducts.php?MOD_NUMBER=13

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am try to use 250 met for spatial resolution and 8days for temporal resolution

Answer (score 7):

There's no need for a `for` (or any other kind of) loop since such stuff is entirely included in the **raster** package. If you want to calculate the NDVI, then basically all you need is

```
## required package
library(raster)

## calculate ndvi from red (band 1) and near-infrared (band 2) channel
ndvi <- overlay(StackBand1, StackBand2, fun = function(x, y) {
  (y-x) / (y+x)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. This question refers to a file with different bands. But what if I have different file directory/folder for NIR and Red? How do you do the NDVI?