# Using R calculating NDVI

Tags: r, ndvi

Is there any function to calculate statistical NDVI in landsat8 package

Comment: Is the "statistical NDVI" something special? You can easily calculate the NDVI like this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163545/using-loop-for-calculating-ndvi

Comment: Wikipedia and basic raster band math should give you all you need.

Comment: Your questions are all very similar and show a lack of interest in self study. You should google more and get a bit more familiar with the R raster package to understand how to work with stacks.

Answer (score 0):

NDVI is always calculated like this:

```
NDVI = (NIR - RED)/(NIR + RED)
```

For Landsat 8 this means

```
NDVI = (Band5 - Band4)/(Band5 + Band4)
```